# Validity of Canada visitor visa in expired passport

Tags: visas, canada, visa-expiration

I entered to Canada on 16th June 22 by visa in my expired passport and a new passport valid for next 5 years. The end of visa in my expired passport is 29th Nov 2022. Can I stay inside Canada till 16th December which is end of my 6 months (according to CIC, date of visa is entry date not expiration date) or my visa is expired.

Comment: did the entry officer writeor stamp a date in your passport?

Answer (score 2):

[Most visitors are allowed to stay in Canada for 6 months. You may be admitted for a shorter time, in which case your passport will be stamped on entry to indicate a shorter duration and you may be given other documentation.](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1016&top=16)

If there is no stamp to say anything different then you are permitted to stay for six months.

The fact that the Visa is in an expired passport is immaterial.